# Is it better practice to have nested consumer of providers (not talking about multi providers) or have one provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

Suppose I have a change notifier class

```
class State extends ChangeNotifier{
}
```

This change notifier change class should be able to trigger update (notify) two widgets where one widget is child of the other.

I am wondering which of these two patterns is better approach when designing flutters apps.

1. Have nested consumers of change notifier objects. Is it good practice to have a consumer that build a widget that have as a child another widget that itself also have its own consumer for same class.

e.g pseudocode for simplicity

```
class Widget1State extends State<Widget1>  {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            Consumer<State>(
                builder: (context, state, _) {
          child: Widget2()
     }
  }
}

class Widget2State extends State<Widget2>  {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            Consumer<State>( // nested consumer here Widget1->Widget2
                builder: (context, state, _) {
          child: ...
     }
  }
}
```

2. Have just one consumer of change notifier at the root and propagate class state as variable?

```
class Widget1State extends State<Widget1>  {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            Consumer<State>(
                builder: (context, state, _) {
          child: Widget2(state /*now i am passing the change notifier as variable*/)
     }
  }
}

class Widget2  extends StatefulWidget {
   State state;
}

class Widget2State extends State<Widget2>  {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            
          child: ...widget.state... // just use widget.state, no need for consumer
  }
}
```

If the better choice is option-2, should i use stateless widget instead?

Thanks a lot for help and sorry if this is stupid question or confusing, i am new to flutter.